# How to test if one graph is a subgraph of another in Networkx?

Tags: python, networkx, directed-graph

I am new to building directed graphs with networkx and I'm trying to work out how to compare two graphs. More specifically, how to tell if a smaller graph is a subgraph (unsure of the exact terminology) of a larger graph

As an example, assume I have the following directed graph:
[image: Graph A]

I would like to be able to check whether a series of smaller graphs are sub-graphs of this initial graph. Returning a True value if they are (graph B), and False if they are not (graph C):

[image: Graph B] Graph B = Sub-graph of Graph A

[image: Graph C] Graph C != Sub-graph of Graph A

***Example Code***

```
import networkx

A = nx.DiGraph()
A.add_edges_from([('A','B'),('B','C'),('C','A')])
nx.draw_networkx(A)


B = nx.DiGraph()
B.add_edges_from([('A','B')])
nx.draw_networkx(B)

C = nx.DiGraph()
C.add_edges_from([('A','B'),('A','C')])
nx.draw_networkx(C)
```

I've had a look through the documentation and cannot seem to find what I need. An alternative I have been considering is to represent the nodes as a sequence of strings, and then searching for each substring in the main graphs string sequence - however, I can't imagine this is the most effecient/effective/stable way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a [subgraph isomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem).

```
nx.isomorphism.DiGraphMatcher(A, B).subgraph_is_isomorphic()
# True

nx.isomorphism.DiGraphMatcher(A, C).subgraph_is_isomorphic()
# False
```

Note that the operation can be slow for large graphs, as the problem is NP-complete.